# Посчитать выражение в строке Python

Tags: python

Как правильно спарсить и посчитать математические выражения в строке в Python?

Нужно чтобы были доступны + - * / sin() cos() tg().. pow(), sqrt(), log() выражения.

eval() -- нет. Знаю, что с ним можно, но выходит очень небезопасно.
Пробовал библиотеку sympy - но с самими функциями как-то криво работает и флоаты не исчесляет.

Comment: 1- что значит "очень небезопасно"? Откуда ввод берётся? 2- Sympy однозначно может float вычислять. Если не знаете как float получить, используя sympy, задайте отдельный вопрос.  3- [sympy также как и eval() "небезопасен"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string#comment26493401_9556473)

Comment: Напишите свой парсер, только какой-нибудь lisp для этого лучше.